# Runtime Test Data for Testscript in TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

I started using Test Complete to automate Desktop application. 
The issue is scripts holds the value which i entered while recording and the value is  hard-coded. 
i want the pass the value during run time. how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you want to do this. If you want to put it to your test as a parameter from another test or using a project's test item, you can define a keyword test parameter (see [Keyword Test Parameters](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/75440/)).

If you want to make a human user specify a value on runtime (although this is not very "automated"), you can create a user form that will request this value (see [User Forms - Overview](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/74256/)).

And if you want to pass a parameter to your test using command line, you can use script to read parameters from the TestComplete command-line, assign a project variable with this value and then use this variable instead of a hard coded value. See [ParamStr Method](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/75054/), [ParamCount Method](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/68418/) and [Project And Project Suite Variables](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/72293/).

And if you want to feed your test with some data from an external source, you can do this using the data-driven testing feature of TestComplete. See [Data-Driven Testing](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/72498/).